# How to retrieve the content of a pull request patch file from a private repo?

Tags: node.js, github, github-api

I have a private repo and I need to get the patch file contents from a pull request. 
I am using [this nodejs api](https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-github).

```
github.pullRequests.get(msg,function(err,p){
    //[...]
    console.log(p.patch_url); //I get the patch url something like: https://github.com/:user/:repo/pull/1.patch
    //[...]
})
```

How can I get the content of that file either using the API or some other method (curl, etc)?
`github.repos.getContent` doesn't seem to help (or I might sending the wrong path for this file).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I missed this:

> Alternative Response Formats
>
> Pass the appropriate media type to fetch diff and patch formats.

from the [GitHub API documentation](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request).

Info regarding the format: [Media](http://developer.github.com/v3/media/#commits-commit-comparison-and-pull-requests):

`application/vnd.github.VERSION.patch`

Comment: How were you able to pass that header using the github package?